# Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi x^2} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, residue-calculus

Calculate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi x^2} dx$ by using $$f(z)=\frac{e^{\pi i z^2}}{\sin{\pi z}}$$
and integrating $f(x)$ over the parallelogram with points $\pm \frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}T$ and letting $T\rightarrow \infty$.

---

My attempt:

I found a source (in German) that does something similar for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}$: [Here under 0.1 the 4. proof](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R(x,exp))

They basically say that I need to look at the integral from $\int_{-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}T}^{ \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}T} f(z) dz$ and $\int_{\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}T}^{ -\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}T} f(z) dz$

and argument, why these two integrals go to $0$ for $T\rightarrow \infty$

For that, do I need to plug in $z=x+iy$, look at the real part of $f(z)=\frac{e^{\pi i z^2}}{\sin{\pi z}}$ and let $x\rightarrow \infty$?

Then the source does something like $f(z)-f(z+a)=e^{-x}$. In my case I thought it is similar to $f(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}z)-f(-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}z)=2\sqrt{i}e^{-\pi z^2}$ which is not the desired $e^{-\pi z^2}$ that I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See also the tenth proof [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf).

Comment: @J.G. yes I think I understand the theory behind it. We have a function without poles so we take a function that has poles and which converges to the desired function by taking $T \rightarrow \infty$. We can therefore use the residue theorem. Correct? But I'm still confused how to use it in my case. I cannot generate $e^{-\pi T^2}$ for some reason.

Comment: Hint: simplify $f(e^{i\pi/4}z-\frac12)-f(e^{i\pi/4}z+\frac12)$, then use parameterizations of the parallelogram's long sides to work out why that's relevant.